# Не могу написать код, который выводит файлы в html-код через тег img

Tags: php, html

Я тут решил написать php-код, который достаёт все файлы из некоторого сборника файлов (пусть его зовут images), а затем находит из них все файлы с расширениями .jpg, .bmp и .png (регистронезависимо, то есть "input.JpG" под описание подходит). Все эти файлы вместе с названиями файлов (типа image.txt) выводятся через таблицу по 5 в ряду изображений посредством HTML.

Сам код приведён ниже:

```
    <?php
$list = scandir('images');
$images = array();
foreach($list as $candidate) {
 $path = pathinfo($candidate);
 if (preg_match("/^(bmp|jpg|png)$/", strtolower($path['extension']))) {
  array_push($images, $path['filename'] . "." . strtolower($path['extension']));
 };
};
echo '<table style="border: 1px solid black; margin: 0px auto;"><tr>';
$i = 0;
foreach($images as $image) {
 echo '<td><img src = \"';
 echo $image;
 echo '\"/>' . $image . '</td>';
 $i++;
 if ($i % 5 == 0) {
  echo '</tr><tr>';
 };
};
echo '</tr></table>';
?>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что часть кода, ответственная за вывод изображения и имени файла, не может полностью вывести все изображения. Может ли кто-нибудь объяснить, как это исправить?

Comment: Эскейпить двойные кавычки в одинарных не требуется, в `\"` - слэш лишний.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Евгений Курмыса, как-то Вы немного перемудрили. Зачем такие сложности?

Вот пример проще:

```php
echo '<table style="border: 1px solid black; margin: 0px auto;">';
foreach (glob("./images/*.{jpg,bmp,png,jpeg}", GLOB_BRACE) as $docFile) {
    echo '<tr><td><img src="' . $docFile . '"></td>';
    echo '<td>Name - ' . $docFile . '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Просто я ещё только начинаю писать на PHP, и пока пишу такие несуразные коды...

За код большое спасибо, буду стараться стремиться к новым высотам и элегантности :)

Answer (score -1):

```
$dir = "C:\\xampp\\***\\m***";


$files1 = scandir($dir);

$arr=['.jpg','.bmp','.png'];

foreach ($files1 as $key => $value) {
    # code...

$filename = "C:\\xampp\\***\\m***".$value;

foreach ($arr as $key1 => $value1) {

$pos2 = stripos($filename, $value1);


if ($pos2 !== false) {
   $fullfilename[]=$filename;

}
}

}

echo'<table  cellspacing="0" border="2" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 200px">';


echo'<tr>';

$i = 0;
foreach ($fullfilename as $key2 => $value2) {
if (file_exists($value2)) {
echo '<td style="width: 100px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap"><img src='.$value2.' width="40" height="40"></td>';
} else {
$zagluhka='C:\\zaglushka.jpg';

  echo '<td style="width: 100px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap"><img src='.$zaglushka.' width="40" height="40"></td>';

}
 $i++;
 if ($i % 5 == 0) {
  echo '</tr><tr>';
 }
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```